# overriding JTree double-click to prevent node expansion?

Tags: java, swing, jtree, double-click

It looks like there are 2 default mechanisms to expand a folder node in a JTree. One is to click on the expanded/collapsed icon next to a node. The other way is to double-click on the node itself.

Is there a way to stop this 2nd mechanism? I would like to override the double-click on a node so it does something (updates another display to show statistics on the node being double-clicked), and would like it to *not* expand/collapse the tree node. (just to be clear: I don't want to prevent the node from being expanded/collapsed, I just want to require the user to click on the expanded/collapsed icon.) How can I do this?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

From the relevant [API page](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTree.html#setToggleClickCount(int)), you would do something like this:

```
JTree tree = new JTree();
tree.setToggleClickCount(0);
```

This means you must use 0 clicks to expand a tree node, effectively disabling double click. This will not interfere with other methods of tree expansion.

Answer (score 3):

Call setToggleClickCount(0) on the JTree

This will effectively disable expanding on double-click.